# How to change the formatting (eg make bold) only the first 5 words typed in a form

Tags: jquery

**I would like to change** the formatting of the first 5 words that a user inputs into a textarea automatically (eg so it looks like this para).

I know that there is a way to get the value of the text input in jquery using:

```
$('input').keyup(function() {
  $('span').text($(this).val());
});
```

However, I have no idea whether it is possible to change the formatting of just the first few words that a user types, while they are typing it. The reason I wish to do this is because I have a comment system where the "title" of the comment is the first five words of the textarea of the comment, and I want people to recognise this while typing (as part of the UI feedback). Can it be done? How? Thanks!

Comment: did you try capturing the 1st 5 words, and replace it with span or b around it?

Comment: Thanks @Gavriel - when you say "capturing the 1st 5 words", how can I do that **as they type** and not in the post-submission phase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('input').keyup(function() {
  var txt = $(this).val();
  var re=new RegExp("\\S+(?: \\S+(?: \\S+(?: \\S+(?: \\S+)?)?)?)?");
  var beginning = re.exec(txt);
  $('span').text(beginning);
  var rest = txt.substring(beginning.length); // this will probably start with a space
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Gavriel. If I want to change the formatting on the fly, can I just add a "addClass()" to the code? Would that work in a form input?